# Why can't I run Python in VS2013

Tags: python, visual-studio-2013, ptvs

I've installed Visual Studio 2013 with Update 4, as well as CPython and Python Tools for Visual Studio, but as soon as I tried to run:

```
print("Hello World")
```

an error occurred, saying `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. Why am I unable to run this application?

Comment: Please file a bug on https://github.com/Microsoft/ptvs/. Be sure to try the most recent version first.

Comment: But I believe I have the most recent version for I downloaded the installer from microsoft itself. But anyways, thank you for your suggestion. I'll be sure to do it.